# Get rid of the "raspberry" and "pi" tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I just started to edit some questions, removing the [raspberry](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raspberry) and [pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi) tags. (and along with that, did some other edits on the body and titles).

Can you help with removing those useless tags and blacklist those tags? I see no use for it as the site *is* about the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Agreed. We are working on getting those tags burninated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both of these tags are gone and blacklisted to prevent use in the future.

Please clean up [untagged](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged)

Comment: I've re-tagged all of those clean-up questions with the correct tags (in my opinion).